# Updating package with Bower

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower

I am trying to update angular 1.0.5 to 1.0.6. I use Yeoman, and when try to update it is installing 1.0.5. I cleared the cache (removed everything from ~/.bower), still get the below log. I checked the [repo](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular/blob/master/angular.js), and it has 1.0.6. Is there a way I can make it update to 1.0.6.

```
bower update angular
bower cloning git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git
..
bower installing angular#v1.0.5

bower info angular
angular 

  Versions:
    - v1.0.6
    - v1.0.5
    - v1.0.4
    - v1.0.3

$ bower --version
0.8.5

 yo --version
1.0.0-beta.3
```

Comment: Try editing bower.json or component.json's version of angular in the "dependencies" field.

Comment: Also don't forget to include any packages that depend on angular in your update command as [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25494049/39396)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have to upgrade to latest version of Bower: `npm update -g bower`

bower-angular 1.0.6 switched from component.json to bower.json which is only supported in Bower >=0.9.0

Answer (score 1):

**For some reason `npm update -g bower` did not work for me.**

I installed `npm-update-packages` module with `$ npm install -g npm-update-packages` and then checked for any package-updates in my `bower.json` file with `$ ncu -m bower`.  The updates were displayed in the console.  Then, I executed `$ ncu -m bower -u` which updated all packages in `bower.json` that required an update.

For more information on this package:
https://github.com/tjunnone/npm-check-updates

Hope this helps.  Thanks.