# why doesn't bower update angular upgrade my angular?

Tags: angularjs, bower

I have angular 1.2.3 and I want to upgrade to 1.2.7

```
> cat bower.json
...
  "dependencies": {
    "json3": "~3.2.4",
    "jquery": "~1.9.1",
    "es5-shim": "~2.0.8",
    "toastr": "~2.0.1",
    "angular-ui-tinymce": "latest",
    "underscore": "~1.5.2",
    "underscore.string": "~2.3.3",
    "angular-ui-utils": "~0.0.4",
    "angular-dragdrop": "~1.0.5",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.2.3",
    "angular-animate": "~1.2.3",
    "angular-resource": "~1.2.3",
    "angular": "~1.2.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.2.3",
    "bootstrap": "~3.0.1",
    "font-awesome": "~4.0.3",
    "angular-bootstrap-affix": "~0.3.0"
  }
...
```

I don't know what the following output even means...., what is it doing?

```
> bower update angular
bower angular#~1.x              cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.7
bower angular#~1.x            validate 1.2.7 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.x
bower angular#>= 1.0.2          cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.7
bower angular#>= 1.0.2        validate 1.2.7 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>= 1.0.2
bower angular#1.2.3             cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.3
bower angular#1.2.3           validate 1.2.3 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.3
bower angular#~1.2.3            cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.7
bower angular#~1.2.3          validate 1.2.7 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.2.3
bower angular#~1.x                 new version for git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.x
bower angular#~1.x             resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.x
bower angular#>= 1.0.2             new version for git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>= 1.0.2
bower angular#>= 1.0.2         resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>= 1.0.2
bower angular#~1.2.3               new version for git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.2.3
bower angular#~1.2.3           resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.2.3
bower angular#~1.x            download https://github.com/angular/bower-angular/archive/v1.2.8-build.2095+sha.28fc80b.tar.gz
bower angular#>= 1.0.2        download https://github.com/angular/bower-angular/archive/v1.2.8-build.2095+sha.28fc80b.tar.gz
bower angular#~1.2.3          download https://github.com/angular/bower-angular/archive/v1.2.8-build.2095+sha.28fc80b.tar.gz
bower angular#>= 1.0.2         extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular#>= 1.0.2        resolved git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.8-build.2095+sha.28fc80b
bower angular#~1.x             extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular#~1.x            resolved git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.8-build.2095+sha.28fc80b
bower angular#~1.2.3           extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular#~1.2.3          resolved git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.8-build.2095+sha.28fc80b
```

nothing changed?  I'm still on 1.2.3

```
> git diff
diff --git a/ngapp/app/bower_components/angular/.bower.json b/ngapp/app/bower_components/angular/.bower.json
index dc9d0b6..842a1f3 100644
--- a/ngapp/app/bower_components/angular/.bower.json
+++ b/ngapp/app/bower_components/angular/.bower.json
@@ -11,6 +11,6 @@
     "commit": "b112b099971f4cf016023bdeb00b267e9bf6dfb5"
   },
   "_source": "git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git",
-  "_target": "~1.2.3",
+  "_target": "1.2.3",
   "_originalSource": "angular"
 }

> bower --version
1.2.8
```

Am I missing something?

```
> bower info angular
.... shows all versions including 1.2.7 and 1.2.8-builds as well
```

Answer (score 17):

I think your dependencies are preventing you from updating angular in isolation.  E.g., look at `bower_components/angular-route/bower.json`.  You will see a specific version of angular listed as a dependency ("1.2.3") and not a `~`/"reasonably close" specifier" ("~1.2.3").  So you are trying to update just angular, but the farthest that bower can take your angular is the current version since you have other packages that depend on exactly that version.

If you do `bower update` then bower will have the opportunity to update all your packages, including angular-route and other packages that are holding angular back.  The updates to these packages will now allow bower to update angular while satisfying dependencies.  Also, I think if you identified all those packages depending on a specific angular version (you can see dependencies with `bower list`) and passed them as arguments like `bower update angular angular-mocks angular-resource angular-route angular-sanitize...` then bower could also perform the update.

Answer (score 7):

I think the problem is about this

```
"angular": "~1.2.3"
```

https://github.com/isaacs/node-semver/

```
"Reasonably close to 1.2.3".
```

so you should change it with

```
"angular": "1.2.7"
```

**UPDATE:**
(it's in the comment but I think it's better point it out)

Note that you can’t pass a package name to the update command and only update that individual package: it will still update ’em all. You can get the latest version of a single package by running bower install ; it will just over-write the version you currently have

Comment: I'm not following.  So I need to modify my bower.json to 1.2.7?  Then do bower install?  You can't upgrade a package from command line?

Comment: @Whistler i thought ~ means auto upgrades until the current version is 1.3. Can you explain this? thx!

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/meet-bower-a-package-manager-for-the-web/       bower update

Note that you can’t pass a package name to the update command and only update that individual package: it will still update ’em all. You can get the latest version of a single package by running bower install <package>; it will just over-write the version you currently have.

Comment: I'm still not too clear on this usage.  After I run `bower update`, git diff showed the bower_components/angular folder wasn't touched, yet bower_components/bootstrap was completely overhauled.  So then I run `bower install angular --save` which then prompts me for different versions, so finally I can select 1.2.7 in the install process which appears to change the files in bower_components.  So why is the behavior inconsistent.  When I ran bower update, it changed all my bootstrap files, and none of my angular files.

Comment: unless, are you saying: specifying specific versions in bower.json, locks the packages to those versions when running bower update, and specifying the tilde ~ in the version allows bower update to upgraded the packages to nearest accepted version as described by the bower.json... so ~3.0.1 allows for climbing to 3.0.3 but a hard version of 1.2.3 does not take you to 1.2.7 or even ask you.