# bower update momentjs not working

Tags: bower

```
> bower list
momentjs#2.2.1 (2.5.1 now available)
```

I go to change my bower.json to

```
{
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "momentjs": "~2.5.1",
 ...
```

And then run

```
> bower cache clean
> bower update momentjs
bower installing momentjs#2.2.1
```

Why am I getting 2.2.1 and not 2.5.1? Have I misunderstood some basics here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [why doesn't bower update angular upgrade my angular?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029679/why-doesnt-bower-update-angular-upgrade-my-angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help page states that the `update` command:

> Updates installed packages to their newest version **according to bower.json**

`~` will [only lookup **patch versions** in the current minor version range](https://github.com/isaacs/node-semver/#ranges) ("prereleases") e.g. `1.2.3 => 1.2.7`.

To update the minor version, e.g. `1.2.3 = > 1.3.5`, use `bower install <package>` instead.

Comment: Ok, great, `bower install` worked! But `bower help update` gives back `usage: bower update OR bower update <package>`. It looks like its accepting an argument, no? `bower --version: 0.9.2`

Comment: oh ok, maybe it's added in the later versions.. anyhow it shouldn't work for `~` either way. i've updated the answer