# ngBoilerplate upgrade to angularJS 1.5.5

Tags: angularjs, bower, ngboilerplate

Recently, I would like to start a new project. So, I clone https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp framework as a starting point.

I have follow the steps to start. And the angular version was installed as 1.2.29.

I would like to install 1.5.5. 
I tried this commend:

> $ bower install angular#1.5.5

But, it stop here...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfr7W.png

I have tried commend

> $ bower cache clean

But it shows the same result.

Any one can help me=[.

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: FYI, bower version: 1.7.9

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why doesn't bower update angular upgrade my angular?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029679/why-doesnt-bower-update-angular-upgrade-my-angular)